# Parsing Google Maps JSON data for Geocoding in JQ (Not JQuery)

Tags: json, google-maps, jq

I am trying to get the Country and City names from Lat and Long values with JQ.

Here is the full example JSON
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=55.397563,10.39870099999996&sensor=false

I pasted returned JSON in [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/),

Tried to select Country and City names, but the closest I get is

```
.results[0].address_components[].short_name
```

How can I specify just bring the nodes where `"types" : [ "country", "political" ]` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear to me what exactly you're looking for.  Each result has a set of types, each address component also has a set of types.  Which one did you want?  We can write a filter that will match what you attempted but considering the data, it will be completely useless to you.  The only item that contains the types you listed is just a country name.

Anyway, assuming you wanted to get a result object that had the types `"country"` and `"political"`, use the `contains()` filter.

```
.results | map(
    select(
        .types | contains(["country","political"])
    )
)
```

Otherwise you'll need to clarify what exactly you wanted from this data set.  An example of the expected results...

Comment: Thank goodness someone already asked and answered this otherwise I'd have given up on organizing my photos using exif GPS json data and these complex rules.

Comment: Is this still working? For me it just returns []

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to do this.

```
/**
*   geocodeResponse is an object full of address data.  
*   This function will "fish" for the right value
*   
*   example: type = 'postal_code' => 
*   geocodeResponse.address_components[5].types[1] = 'postal_code'
*   geocodeResponse.address_components[5].long_name = '1000'
* 
*   type = 'route' => 
*   geocodeResponse.address_components[1].types[1] = 'route'
*   geocodeResponse.address_components[1].long_name = 'Wetstraat'
*/
function addresComponent(type, geocodeResponse, shortName) {
  for(var i=0; i < geocodeResponse.address_components.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < geocodeResponse.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
      if (geocodeResponse.address_components[i].types[j] == type) {
        if (shortName) {
          return geocodeResponse.address_components[i].short_name;
        }
        else {
          return geocodeResponse.address_components[i].long_name;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

The way to use it; an example:

```
...
myGeocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[1]) {
    var country     = addresComponent('country', results[1], true);
    var postal_code = addresComponent('postal_code', results[1], true);
    ...
  }
});
...
```

I used it here: [saving marker data into db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484126/saving-marker-data-into-db/26487615#26487615)

Answer (score 0):

Assign the json to results variable, var results = {your json}.
 Then try this :

```
for( var idx in results.results)
{
    var address = results.results[idx].address_components;
    for(var elmIdx in address)
    {
        if(address[elmIdx].types.indexOf("country") > -1 &&
           address[elmIdx].types.indexOf("political") > -1)
        {
           address[elmIdx].short_name //this is the country name
           address[elmIdx].long_name  //this is the country name

        }
    }
}
```